# Image stretching with container on hover

Tags: html, css, image

When I hover over the red box, the reddit logo stretches with it, any way to fix this? I hope the snippet will help you understand my problem. Seems like it's a problem with "translate: scaleY();", but I can't use transitions or animations because I'm making like a card and elements push each other.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
}

li {
list-style: none;
}

#card {
    width: 460px;
    height: 350px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    position: absolute;
}

#socialLinks {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 0;
}

#socialLinks li:hover {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
}

#socialLinks li {
    width: 152px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    border-width: 1px;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transform: scaleY(1);
}

#socialLink1 {
    background: tomato;
}

.logoReddit {
    width: 85px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="card">
                <ul id="socialLinks">
                <li id="socialLink1">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img
                        class="logoReddit" src="https://i.ibb.co/1QWXV8g/reddit-logo.png" alt="reddit-logo">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these CSS rules:

```
#socialLinks li .logoReddit {
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

#socialLinks li:hover .logoReddit {
  transform: scaleY(0.9);
}
```